How can I access uploaded file submitted via Forminator?
Currently I am using Forminator, and one of my forms is used to upload users' Microsoft Excel files so that further analysis based on that can be conducted.
I literally have no experience for WordPress, and what I have in my implementation is:
add_action( 'forminator_custom_form_submit_before_save_entry', 'handle_forminator_file_upload', 10, 3 );

function handle_forminator_file_upload( $entry, $form_id, $field_data_array ) {

    $target_form_id = 306; // I am sure this is correct

    if ( $form_id == $target_form_id ) {
        
        $file_data = $field_data_array[0]['value'];

        $file_path = $file_data['file']['file_path'];

        $file_content = file_get_contents( $file_path );
        
        error_log('file content:' . $file_content);
    }
}

Logging the content of the file is just for a test, but nothing was there in the debug.log, the implementation is not working well.
I am just wondering how can I get access to the file uploaded by the user after they submitted their files.
Thanks.

use "error_log" at the start of the function to see data your receive.

We need to made few tweaks in code to make sure it is working fine.
add_action( 'forminator_custom_form_submit_before_save_entry', 'handle_forminator_file_upload', 10, 3 );

function handle_forminator_file_upload( $entry, $form_id, $field_data_array ) {
    $target_form_id = 306; // Here we need to ensure that 306 is the correct form ID.

    if ( $form_id == $target_form_id ) {
        // Here we are looping through the field data array to find the file upload field.
        foreach ( $field_data_array as $field ) {
            // Here we are checking if the field type is 'file'.
            if ( 'file' === $field['type'] && ! empty( $field['value']['file'] ) ) {
                // Here we are retrieving the file data.
                $file_data = $field['value']['file'];

                // Here we are getting the uploaded file's path.
                $file_path = $file_data['file_path'];

                // This is to check if the file exists before attempting to read it.
                if ( file_exists( $file_path ) ) {
                    $file_content = file_get_contents( $file_path );

                    // This is to log the file content for debugging.
                    error_log( 'File content: ' . $file_content );
                } else {
                    error_log( 'File does not exist at path: ' . $file_path );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

